Error code 1290 - not understanding other thread's recco
I am using mysql workbench 8.0.36.  I am trying to create a new table and populate it with data from a CSV file.  I keep getting error code 1290 --secure-file-priv option issue.  I've relocated my CSV file to the Uploads folder in MySQL and keep getting this error. I have seen threads here, and elsewhere, with suggestions about changing settings and whatnot, but none of them are resonating.  If I put the file in the secure Uploads folder and am referencing it correctly as 'C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQLServer 8.2/Uploads/Myfile.csv' and keep getting the error.  I also tried 'C:ProgramData\MySQL\MySQLServer 8.2\Uploads\Myfile.csv' and get the same error.  I've seen someting about changing my.ini but that is the part I get incredibly lost on.  I've spent quite a bit of time on this project and I just need this issue solve so I can move forward.  Thanks for any help
See above for what I tried and what happened.

MySQL server has been started with --secure-file-priv option.
Use SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "secure_file_priv"; to see the default directory.
Now you can move your file to the directory specified by secure-file-priv or disable it.
